# Splitting a string that includes html tags into it's building blocks in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have strings such as:

```
part one<p>part two</p><p>part three <a href="/links/link1">part four</a>part five</p><li>part six <a href="/links/link2">part seven</a>part eight</li>
```

and I want to generate a python list like:

```
['part one','part two','part three','/links/link1','part four','part five','part six','/links/link2','part seven','part eight']
```

The order in the list should follow the order of occurrence in the string. The strings might have no/more/less tags and nested tags.

I've read answers to some fairly similar questions, but couldn't find one that addresses this specific problem. I've tried packages like BeautifulSoup and such, but couldn't extract all parts and in the order of occurrence.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Check out [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for this kind of task. Steep learning curve, but worth it in the end. Trying to do this stuff with regex (say) will only lead to frustration.

Comment: I tried both BeautifulSoup and regex, but couldn't figure it out. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the built-in HTML parser class to walk the string and keep track of the bits you need.

```py
from html.parser import HTMLParser


class BuildingBlocksParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bits = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        for key, value in attrs:
            self.bits.append(value)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.bits.append(data)


parser = BuildingBlocksParser()
parser.feed(
    'part one<p>part two</p><p>part three <a href="/links/link1">part four</a>part five</p><li>part six <a href="/links/link2">part seven</a>part eight</li>'
)
print(parser.bits)
```

outputs

```
['part one', 'part two', 'part three ', '/links/link1', 'part four', 'part five', 'part six ', '/links/link2', 'part seven', 'part eight']
```

Comment: This solution is very neat and I like it. However, in case of `class` attributes, it chops them as a separate part in the final list.

Comment: What do you mean? In any case, your example didn't have a class attribute at all, and didn't specify how to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` with recursion:

```
import bs4
s = 'part one<p>part two</p><p>part three <a href="/links/link1">part four</a>part five</p><li>part six <a href="/links/link2">part seven</a>part eight</li>'
def get_data(d):
  if isinstance(d, bs4.element.NavigableString):
     yield d
  if d.name == 'a':
     yield d['href']
  yield from [i for b in getattr(d, 'contents', []) for i in get_data(b) if b != '\n']

print(list(get_data(bs4.BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser'))))
```

Output:

```
['part one', 'part two', 'part three ', '/links/link1', 'part four', 'part five', 'part six ', '/links/link2', 'part seven', 'part eight']
```